# Chrome Extension - Sending Get Requests From Content Script To Be Executed In The Background.js

Tags: javascript, ajax, google-chrome-extension

Here's my problem. I need to get some data from the current document / webpage using the content script. Okay.

With this data I will perform a fetch request.

I have already tried to perform said fetch request in the content script.

Needless to say, it does not work. The response is empty, and I cannot parse it into json.

```js
fetch('https://mywebsite.com/myendpoint?productId=' + product_id).then(res => res.json()).then(data => console.log(data));
}
```

The following code, when executed in the content script does not work.

I am receiving this error in the console.

```
Uncaught (in promise) SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at content.js:898
```

Now,  **when I execute it in the console** , it does actually work and returns a json object.

So I think that what I need to do is, somehow send the URL to the background.js file to have it executed & then send the results of that back to the content-script so I can use them to change elements of the DOM.

I have no idea how to communicate between the content-script and background.js, let alone execute entire functions between them

so that is what I need help with.

Comment: Use [messaging](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging) and see [demo extensions](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/samples).

Comment: Ok I fixed it. But now I'm having an issue where my sendMessage() response will not wait for my fetch to finish....any ideas how to fix this?

Comment: Yeah, do `return true` right before the end of onMessage listener.